# Methods for supervised regression learning

Tags: regression, machine-learning, svm, random-forest, boosting

What ML methods should I try for a data set of around 1000 samples? The output variable is dependent on say 10 regressors of which 8 are real numbers and the other 2 are categorical. Or they might just be real numbers only.

Comment: Try e.g. svm, RF and ridge regression. Depending on package categorical vars may have to be manually converted to dummy variables for svm and ridge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there is no rule for such a question like this, but just to give a simple idea, lets take a look at the:

> [Microsoft Azure Machine Learning: Algorithm Cheat Sheet](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/6/1/A613E11E-8F9C-424A-B99D-65344785C288/microsoft-machine-learning-algorithm-cheat-sheet-v2.pdf)